Delta live tables cdc
How can I ingest raw vendor data from Azure Data Factory (ADF) into a Delta Live Table in Databricks, specifically targeting new files added daily? Can I create a non-streaming Delta Live Table to handle this batch-like ingestion process, and is it feasible to use Cloud Files to efficiently load only the newly added files?
My question is can I use non streaming Table and using cloud files to ingest newly added files

what do you mean from ADF? ADF is not a storage medium. Am not clear what your requirements are but You can use Autoloader to load only the new data/files into a Delta live table. But then again you can use autoloader to load the new data to a NON DLT table as well. If you use autoloader, the table will be streaming by default. So you need to ask yourself if you need DLT or not.

In Databricks Delta Live Table, you can define only Streaming Tables, Materialized Views and Views.
Auto Loader incrementally and efficiently processes new data files as they arrive in cloud storage. It provides a Structured Streaming source called cloudFiles. Given an input directory path on the cloud file storage, the cloudFiles source automatically processes new files as they arrive, with the option of also processing existing files in that directory. Auto Loader has support for both Python and SQL in Delta Live Tables.
You can use Auto Loader to process billions of files to migrate or backfill a table. Auto Loader scales to support near real-time ingestion of millions of files per hour.
